# How to insert records in master table using EntityFrameWork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6. I have inserted records in category table using seed method and it is working fine. Now as per new requirement I have a new category which needs to be inserted in Category table.

What is good approach for doing this.

As per my understanding of EF what I can do is that

1) Insert this record using EF statements. and then drop tables and re-run . Update-Database -verbose using Package manager console.

2) Or write sql insert scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you want to copy all records of old category table into new category table

In this case you can run the following EF code for one time, after that you can delete the old and work with new one.

```
List<OldCategory > oldCategoryList = new List<OldCategory>();
List<NewCategory > newCategoryList = new List<NewCategory>();

oldCategoryList = dbContext.OldCategory .ToList();
foreach (var item in oldCategoryList )
{
   newCategoryList .Add(item);
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I resolved this problem by using the following technique. I used AddOrUpdate() method which work as upsert query. I replaced each Add() with AddorUpdate() inside the seed method and re-running seed method is inserting only new enteries.